# How to Limit characters in select2?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2, simple-form

I'd like to limit number characters of string in select2 in ten (10) characters, for example:

```
"apple", is valid.. has 5 characters
"book", is valid.. has 4 characters
"Incomprehensibilities", is invalid... has 21 characters, permited max 10 characters
```

I have the select2 code but I don't know how to limit the number of characters

```
$("#customer_tag_ids").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 5,
    multiple: true,
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    createTag: function (params) {
      if (params.term.match(/^(?![\d ])[a-z\d ]*$/i)) {
        // Return null to disable tag creation
        return {
          id: params.term,
          text: params.term,
          tag: true
        }
      }
      return null;
    },
    language: {
      maximumSelected: function (e) {
        return I18n.t('customers.alert.limit_max');
      },

      inputTooShort: function (e) {
        return I18n.t('customers.alert.limit_min');
      },

      noResults: function(){
        return I18n.t('customers.alert.not_result_found');
      }
    },
  });
```

Comment: you could use plain javascript like this: text: params.term.substring(0, 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your `createTag` option to prevent user input text that has more than 10 chars. Also I added a `div` tag below to give a warning message whenever the user want to create a new tag.

### Another solution

At first I thought that we can use the event [select2:selecting](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events)

> select2:selecting Triggered before a result is selected. This event can be prevented.

That means you can catch the event `$('#customer_tag_ids').on('select2:selecting, (event) => { // do something })`
and then use the method `event.preventDefault()` to prevent selecting the value.

But then I realized you've already have some conditions inside the `creatTag` option, and you may want to check the condition and show the message to the new tags only, so I end up with the below solution.

```js
$("#customer_tag_ids").select2({
  maximumSelectionLength: 5,
  multiple: true,
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
  createTag: function(params) {
    let text = params.term;
    $('#warning-text').show();
    if (text.length <= 10) {
      $("#warning-text").text(`"${text}", is valid.. has ${text.length} characters`);
    } else {
      $("#warning-text").text(`"${text}", is invalid... has ${text.length} characters, permited max 10 characters
`);
      // return null to prevent create new tag
      return null;
    }

    if (params.term.match(/^(?![\d ])[a-z\d ]*$/i)) {
      // Return null to disable tag creation
      return {
        id: params.term,
        text: params.term,
        tag: true
      }
    } else {
      $("#warning-text").text(`"${text}", is invalid... it's doesn't match the pattern /^(?![\d ])[a-z\d ]*$/i
`);
    }
    return null;
  },
  language: {
    maximumSelected: function(e) {
      // return I18n.t('customers.alert.limit_max');
    },

    inputTooShort: function(e) {
      // return I18n.t('customers.alert.limit_min');
    },

    noResults: function() {
      // return I18n.t('customers.alert.not_result_found');
    }
  },
});

// Hide the warning text when open/close the dropdown
$("#customer_tag_ids").on("select2:open, select2:close", (e) => {
  $("#warning-text").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="customer_tag_ids" class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" style="width: 300px">
  <option value="text-1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="text-2">Text 2</option>
</select>

<div id="warning-text" style="margin-top: 50px">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by setting the `maxlength` attribute of the class `.select2-search__field` in the `select2:open` event.

e.g.

```js
$("#customer_tag_ids").select2({
  maximumSelectionLength: 5,
  multiple: true,
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
  createTag: function(params) {
    if (params.term.match(/^(?![\d ])[a-z\d ]*$/i)) {
      // Return null to disable tag creation
      return {
        id: params.term,
        text: params.term,
        tag: true
      }
    }
    return null;
  },
  language: {
    maximumSelected: function(e) {
      return I18n.t('customers.alert.limit_max');
    },

    inputTooShort: function(e) {
      return I18n.t('customers.alert.limit_min');
    },

    noResults: function() {
      return I18n.t('customers.alert.not_result_found');
    }
  },
});

// This limits the select2 input to 10 characters
$('#customer_tag_ids').select2().on('select2:open', function() {
    $('.select2-search__field').attr('maxlength', 10);
});
```

```css
#customer_tag_ids { width: 300px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="customer_tag_ids">
    <option value="text-1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="text-2">Text 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you don't want every search field limited and only the one for the current select/select2, then you can instead use: `$(this).data("select2").dropdown.$search.attr('maxlength', 6);`